# Write logical expression which is true

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

Write logical expression that is true when at most two numbers A, B, C are nonpositive. Can you answer this one?

Teacher stated that answer is 
`!(A =< 0 && B =< 0 && C <= 0)`
and
`A > 0 || B > 0 || C > 0`.

I still don't understand her answer, can you help me?

Comment: Why don't you ask her ?

Comment: `Write logical expression that is true when at most two numbers A, B, C are nonpositive.` == `Write logical expression that is true when at least one number is greater than zero.`

Comment: If the expression is true if at most two of three numbers are non-positive, the only way it can be false is if all three are negative.

Comment: `A =< 0` is not valid C++. Was it, perhaps, `A <= 0`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now, the question states that at most 2 out of A, B, C are non-positive. So, it means that condition that includes the 3 numbers and returns true would be 
1.

```
!(A =< 0 && B =< 0 && C <= 0)
```

Here, we know that either one of A, B or C is greater than 0. Hence, it will return true.
2.

```
A > 0 || B > 0 || C > 0
```

Here, the same reason would hold and at least one of them would return true.

Comment: `A =< 0` is not valid C++. If the expressions were written properly (A <= 0`), the **result** of that expression would be true. Expressions do not **return** values; **functions** return values.

Answer (score 1):

You teacher has applied the De Morgan's law which says:

```
not (A or B) = not A and not B;
```

and

```
not (A and B) = not A or not B
```

Have a look to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/De_Morgan%27s_laws for the full explanation

Answer (score 0):

Working Code.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

//Function for logic

bool myFun(int a,int b,int c)
{

    bool conditionFirst=!(a <= 0 && b <= 0 && c <= 0);

    bool condintionSecond=(a > 0 || b > 0 || c > 0);

    if(conditionFirst==true && condintionSecond==true)
    return true;
    else
    return false;

}

int main() {
    int a,b,c;
    cin>>a>>b>>c;
    if(myFun(a,b,c))
    cout<<"True";
    else
    cout<<"False";

}
```